# Git says jupyter notebook file has unstaged changes, but no diff

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook

I run into this problem every once in a while:

```
 > git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   scripts/encoder-check.ipynb
```

then the diff

```
> git diff
>
```

nothing is there. It might be file permissions related, but I don't know how to determine this. No matter what I do, the file always shows as changed.

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
git restore scripts/encoder-check.ipynb
git checkout develop -- scripts/encoder-check.ipynb
```

nothing makes it go away. This prevents me from pull-rebasing for instance, but I want to know what this issue is. I've only ever seen it with Jupyter notebooks

---

Update: With `git add -p`, it actually does show me something to stage:

```
> git add -p
diff --git a/scripts/encoder-check.ipynb b/scripts/encoder-check.ipynb
index 8e051be59..6281c219b 100644
--- a/scripts/encoder-check.ipynb
+++ b/scripts/encoder-check.ipynb
@@ -130,9 +130,7 @@
   {
    "cell_type": "code",
    "execution_count": null,
-   "metadata": {
-    "scrolled": true
-   },
+   "metadata": {},
    "outputs": [],
    "source": [
     "# ideally full bars with the same height at all hours\n",
(1/1) Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,e,?]?
```

So I'm wondering: What kind of filter functionality prevents this diff from getting erased?

Comment: can you please check `git check-attr -a -- scripts/encoder-check.ipynb` ?

Comment: You probably have a filter (in this case a diff filter, but there may be additional ones as well) to trim away the `metadata` values in `*.ipynb` files.

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you solve it? I want to discard my changes but they just won't go away!